# Problem with send, recv and NULL pointer in C

Tags: c, pointers, client-server

My code has a problem which I don't understand at all. Here is the code from the server:

```
usr = uslist_return(&users,i);
if(usr != NULL)
{
            send(client,usr,sizeof(usr),0);
            //Some extra code
}
else
{
            utmp.userid = -1;
            send(client,&utmp,sizeof(utmp),0);
}
```

Here is the code from the client:

```
recv(sock,tmp,sizeof(tmp),0);
if(tmp->userid > 0)
{
       //Some Code
}
else
{
       //Some other code
}
```

The problem here is that although I check that send() doesn't send a NULL pointer, the pointer that send() sends ends up being NULL. Maybe it's from recv(). I don't have the slightest idea.

Ignore uslist_return(...). It's just a function that returns a pointer. And the utmp is the same type (but not a pointer) as usr.

Edit: The server sends a pointer in if brackets and a struct in else brackets. The problem occures when the server sends the pointer usr and the client gets it and saves it in the pointer tmp (same type pointers). I Haven't check the else case yet, due to this.

Edit 2: Thanks Martin James for commenting that. It appears that recv() returns -1. Perror shows that the error is Bad Address. I don't know what this is.

Comment: *the pointer I that send() sends ends up being NULL* - what does it mean? How do you know this? Anyway, `sizeof(usr)` is a size of a pointer, not the pointed data.

Comment: You want to debug either the client or server.  netcat aka nc or socket is useful utilities to play either.  In the first case, usr != NULL, it sounds like a list of users but you do sizeof(usr) which is the size of the variable not count of users.  In the usr == NULL, you don't tell us what utmp is.  Please provide a [mre]

Comment: if `usr` is a pointer `sizeof(usr)` is the size of the pointer (probably 4 or 8), not the size of what it points to.

Comment: send(), recv() return values, you must not ignore them:(

Comment: "_Perror shows that the error is Bad Address. I don't know what this is._" Probably because the value of `tmp` is not a valid address. I can't tell for sure because your code is incomplete. However, the piece of code you posted does not seem to be correct. You could improve your question by creating a [mre].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you are confusing a *count* of users, say, 27, with the *size* in byte of the variable `usr`, say, 8 bytes. The `send()` argument `len` is number of bytes you are sending.  If each record is uniform in size then it's count * sizeof(record), otherwise you need to sum the size of each record.

Also, sending pointers, as you allude to, does not usually make sense as server and client use different address spaces.

Check return value of `send()` and `recv()`.

Comment: I don't really understand that. Because, in other places of the code, I use pointers and nothing happens. It seems that you are right, though, because I haven't reached those points in the code, yet. First I have to do that. I will check it.

Comment: Could I use send(sock,&(*usr),sizeof(*usr),0)? I don't know if is this the same as before.

Comment: You haven't told us what type usr is, so it's hard to help you.   If it's an int and you just have one of them, yes, then `send(..., &usr, sizeof(usr), ..)` is the way to send the value stored in usr.  You are NOT sending a pointer.   If usr is a struct, then you may need to serialize it (convert values, and ensure pointers are converted to something that makes sense to client).

Comment: Indeed the problem was sending the pointer. The usr is a struct. I had to pass each member separately (int,char etc, not complex types). But, when I was sending a struct (not a pointer) by mistake, and the client received just some bytes, no error was occur, except from the server waiting the client to receive the remaining bytes.

Comment: Just a heads-up that there are libraries to help you with (de)serializing aka marshaling.  Traditionally, you would use ASN.1, these days you might use JSON, or you can use a dedicated library like Cap'n Proto or Protobuf.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I don't have a big knowledge on specific things in coding. Just recently I learned about DLLs and how they work. I know about JSON, because of a book for python, but I know only it's existence. Do you have any recommendation for general coding topics? Any website that discuss code in general? Something particular for newcomers? I'd like to point out that this is my first 'big' project (~= 4850 lines), written in C, which I found very frustrating after my experience with python, but also very specific, and I like that.

Comment: Keep learning, solve your problems, try different things.  Some times Python is the right answer, some times it's C.  If you haven't read the Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie: "C Programming Language, 2nd Edition".  It's a bit dated but still a great book.   Brian Kernighan, Rob Pike: "The Practice of Programming" is great too.

Comment: Thank you very much. I took a pick on the first book, but, because we did C on University, I lost my intersest. I'll check it again. Anyway, thanks for all the help and tips. I appreciate it.